# Python 'unittest.main()' not working properly

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve an problem that is:-

- Define a class `TestIsEvenMethod`, which is derived from `unittest.TestCase` class.

  - Hint : Import `unittest` module and use `TestCase` utility of it.
- Define a test `test_isEven1`, inside `TestIsEvenMethod`, that checks if `isEven(5)` returns `False` or not.

  - Hint : Use `assertEqual` method to verify the function output with expected output.
- Add the statement `unittest.main()`, outside the class definition.

My code for above Problem

```
def isEven(num):
  return num%2==0

import unittest
class TestIsEvenMethod(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_isEven1(self):
    self.assertEqual(isEven(5), False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

However I get the following errors:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: /root/ (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '/root/'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: True
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your python installation or environment. Your script runs fine if simply started with python. Are you using a Jupyter notebook? If yes, [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2746) looks very similar to the problem you are reporting.

Comment: Is the use of `unittest` relevant here?

Answer (score 1):

You should write in **main** function, this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

  s = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestIsEvenMethod)
  unittest.TextTestRunner().run(s)
```